# Capture iOS done button click. Using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, inputaccessoryview

On iOS browser forms, an accessory bar is shown with Done button and next/prev buttons to move between fields.
I would like to capture the Done button click event on the accessory Bar and perform some custom action.
JQuery/ JQuery mobile solutions are welcome.

I do not want to use blur/focusout, because blur is called even when other elements are tapped.
I would like to submit the form when this Done button is called and not submit when other actions happen.

I have already tried binding the keypress event with keycode 13. But it captures only the event when user presses done/submit key on the bottom of the keyboard and not the button on accessory bar.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092363/need-to-identify-the-done-button-click-in-ios-edit-keyboard-using-javascript