# How to capture "Clear" event on input type date for IOS native date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I haven't found the right solution for this yet so here it goes.  I built an app for iOS devices which uses the input type=date to pull up the date picker.  The date picker comes with a < > Clear and Done button.  Unfortunately for me if I use jQuery's $(document).on("change... when you touch the Clear button it produces no result.  I am wondering if there is a way to capture these control buttons events?  I would ultimately like to clear multiple fields with the press of the clear button.  Is this possible?  I also tried:

```
$(document).on("clear", "input[type='date']", function(){
    ...some code...
});
```

or could I use the webkit selectors somehow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092363/need-to-identify-the-done-button-click-in-ios-edit-keyboard-using-javascript